# How to catch filter selection event in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to store selection and deselection of datasets of a charts.js chart. Therefore I need to catch the filter selection as an event. How to do this?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes perfect thx. Onclick needs to be copyed to preserve behaviour:  lineChart.options.legend.onClick=function(t,e){
           
            var n = e.datasetIndex
                  , i = this.chart
                  , a = i.getDatasetMeta(n);
                a.hidden = null === a.hidden ? !i.data.datasets[n].hidden : null,
                i.update()
        }